# Is there is any way to implement FirebaseListAdapter in a Tab view?

Tags: android, listview, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui, tabview

I have created a tab view in an activity. Now I want to display the list items inside each tabs which is to be retrieved from Firebase.

I can retrieve and show the data inside an activity. But I don't know how to use the `FirebaseListAdapter` inside a Fragment. The `FirebaseListAdapter` needs the first argument as an `Activity`, but how can I pass the Fragment as an Activity?

```
childRef = databaseReference.child(str);
FirebaseListAdapter<Leave> firebaseListAdapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<Leave>(
            this,
            Leave.class,
            R.layout.leavelistview,
            childRef
    ) {
        @Override
        protected void populateView(View v, Leave model, int position) {
            ((TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.lv_staffname)).setText(model.getName());
            ((TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.lv_type)).setText(model.getType());
            ((TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.lv_duration)).setText(model.getDuration());
        }
    };
    listView.setAdapter(firebaseListAdapter);
```

This is the code that I used in an activity. But implementing this inside a fragment is giving me an error as we can't pass `this` for a fragment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call `getActivity()` on the fragment to pass it to the adapter. Like this:

```
FirebaseListAdapter<Leave> firebaseListAdapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<Leave>(
            getActivity(),
            Leave.class,
            R.layout.leavelistview,
            childRef
    ) {
        @Override
        protected void populateView(View v, Leave model, int position) {
            ((TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.lv_staffname)).setText(model.getName());
            ((TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.lv_type)).setText(model.getType());
            ((TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.lv_duration)).setText(model.getDuration());
        }
    };
```

Comment: its still giving me error saying expected parameter is `android.app.activity`

Comment: Try using `getActivity()`

Comment: Can you check this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42040064/how-to-initialize-a-listview-inside-a-fragment-of-tab-view-android

Comment: @MbaiMburu you're probably using the adapter on an Actity and not in a fragment. Use `MainActivity.this` instead. (Replace MainActivity by the name of your activity)