# How to initialize a Listview inside a fragment of Tab view android?

Tags: java, listview, android-fragments, firebaseui

I have an activity which has three tabs. One fragment for each tabs. In the xml of the fragment layout I have a listview. I need to initialize this list view and populate it with data from the firebase. How can I do that?

My activity code is

```
public class AccountActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
private ViewPager mViewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_account);

    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);


    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            startActivity(new Intent(AccountActivity.this,AddLeaveActivity.class));
        }
    });

}


/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
    /**
     * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
     * fragment.
     */
    private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    /**
     * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
     * number.
     */
    public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
        PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        if(getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER) == 1){
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_today, container, false);
            return rootView;
        } else if(getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER) == 2){
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tomorrow, container, false);
            return rootView;
        } else {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dayafter, container, false);
            return rootView;
        }


        //View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_account, container, false);

        //TextView textView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.section_label);
        //textView.setText(getString(R.string.section_format, getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));

        //return rootView;
    }
}

/**
 * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
 * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
 */
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
        // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).
        return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 3 total pages.
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return "TODAY";
            case 1:
                return "TOMORROW";
            case 2:
                return "DAY AFTER";
        }
        return null;
    }
}
}
```

and my fragment.java is

```
public class TodayFragment extends Fragment {
// TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
// the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

// TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
private String mParam1;
private String mParam2;

private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

public TodayFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

/**
 * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
 * this fragment using the provided parameters.
 *
 * @param param1 Parameter 1.
 * @param param2 Parameter 2.
 * @return A new instance of fragment TodayFragment.
 */
// TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
public static TodayFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
    TodayFragment fragment = new TodayFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference();
DatabaseReference childRef;

ListView listView;
TextView textView;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
        mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
    }

    textView = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.todayfragmentheader);
    textView.setText("Inside onCreate Fragment1");

    listView = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.listview);

    displaylistview("20170130");


}

private void displaylistview(String str){
    childRef = databaseReference.child(str);
//    //databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReferenceFromUrl(leavedate);

    FirebaseListAdapter<Leave> firebaseListAdapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<Leave>(
            getActivity(),
            Leave.class,
            R.layout.leavelistview,
            childRef
    ) {
        @Override
        protected void populateView(View v, Leave model, int position) {
            ((TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.lv_staffname)).setText(model.getName());
            ((TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.lv_type)).setText(model.getType());
            ((TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.lv_duration)).setText(model.getDuration());
        }
    };
    listView.setAdapter(firebaseListAdapter);
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_today, container, false);
}

// TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
    if (mListener != null) {
        mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
    }
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
        mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
    }
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mListener = null;
}

/**
 * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
 * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
 * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
 * activity.
 * <p>
 * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
 * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
 * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
 */
public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    // TODO: Update argument type and name
    void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
}
}
```

Here the problem is not only the data is populating but also its not setting the text of the `textview`. But the data is populating and listing if I am using an activity. So I guess the data retrieving code is correct.

So where can is initialize the `listview` inside a fragment?